# Get page numbers containing a specific object to show at run time

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I created a box object(Red box). When I run the application and when report is show, it tends to other pages. How can I get the number that determines which page it's on?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qp2wiWo.png]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for clarity's sake? It's difficult to tell what the "red box" is or what purpose it serves.

Comment: sorry, i can not add image. my reputation just one point.  The red box is the box object has been created by crystal report design mode. I am sorry for my language.

Comment: I have added a link. Please check.

Comment: At what section in the report do you need to use the page number? In the Page Header? The Report Footer?

Comment: i don't know which page has the red box when report show.  if I know,I will order the report to show that page immediately when I change the items at the left table.

Comment: I do not think Crystal Reports has the capability to suppress entire pages like that, much less detect the presence while printing records. Perhaps you could make a separate, nearly-identical report that displays nothing but the section with the red box?

Comment: Do you ask me? Sorry I don't sure i understand you. you are trying to say there are not the method. Right?